# Symbol not found when building App including MapKit

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios13, xcode11

When using the new Xcode 11 beta. I'm getting the following crash while running my app that uses MapKit. Xcode 10 works fine. Also creating a new project and adding a Map with Mapkit works fine.

A simple web search doesn't yield anything.

Any clues where to look to solve this problem?

Xcode 11 beta 1:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NavigationConfig_MapLocalizeLabels
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
  Expected in: /Users/Teameh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dejdjcwzzweszweqllhjxqbarbsp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Navigation.framework/Navigation
 in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
```

Xcode 11 beta 3:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NavigationConfig_MapLocalizeLabels
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
  Expected in: /Users/Teameh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dejdjcwzzweszweqllhjxqbarbsp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Navigation.framework/Navigation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
```

I've split my code up in multiple frameworks, one is called `Navigation.framework`, could that be the issue? This was not a problem with Xcode 10.

---

**Update 1**

As suggested by in the comments, this is not fixed by [adding MapKit to the embedded frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kb82.png). I thought system frameworks should not be added to the embedded frameworks, and [this shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idi14.png) that that does not work.

---

**Update 2**

I've removed MapKit and all the code referencing it but still I get the same crash.

Comment: Most of the times that error occurs it due the the framework not being present in embedded binaries, I know since it's a native framework it shouldn't be necessary, but since it's a beta you can give it a try and see if works, please let us know if it did.

Comment: That does not work (I've added a note at the bottom of my answer)

Comment: I assume you have already tried to clean your Derived Data folder

Comment: Yeah, removed it completely. Did not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you stated you have your own Navigation Framework.
Xcode is looking for `_NavigationConfig_MapLocalizeLabels` in your own Navigation Framework instead of Mapkit's Navigation framework.

Renaming your Navigation framework to something else should do the trick.

Comment: Yes this worked! Can't find any docs on this 'Navigation' framework though.. Maybe a new private Apple framework?